# how to replace css assigned for a tab with jQuery css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I applied jQuery tabs to my webpage, but its functionality depends on one existing css class which is used in an JavaScript file. If I remove that class then tab won't work if I keep that css then jQuery css gets overridden. I am confused a lot please help. The class name is "Tabs" you can find in mark up. I have attached both css class and JavaScript that is using that class.

The JavaScript file is as below. Stackoverflow is not allowing me to add JavaScript file and css any body send me your mail id I will send the code please.

```
<div id="Tabs1"  class="Tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a id="Course" href="#COURSE" onclick="handleTab('1')">Course (<asp:Label ID="lblcourse" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>)</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="General" href="#GENERAL" onclick="handleTab('2')">General (<asp:Label ID="lblgeneral" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>)</a>
    </li> 
    <li>
      <a id="Group" href="#GROUP" onclick="handleTab('3')">Group (<asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Visible="true"></asp:Label>)</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: did you using this one ? https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: You do not need to copy the whole .js or .css files, just paste a few code snippets or provide us with a Fiddle. It would help a lot.